# VB.Net How to attach a handler to a generic class

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a class 'oBnd' defined as Object  that can be assigned as type clsBound or clsClaim.
Claim and bound are identical from the outside, same methods etc.

I call the various properties using 'CallByName'
ie `Dim Current As String = CallByName(oBnd, PropName, CallType.Get)`

When a property is changed in either class the DirtyStatus event is raised by that class.

I am having a problem attaching to this event.

If I try

```
 AddHandler oBnd.DirtyStatus, AddressOf oBnd_DirtyStatus
```

I get the error "DirtyStatus is not an event of Object"  I guess that makes sense as clearly object know nothing of my dirtystatus.

I tried using:

```
 AddHandler DirectCast(oBnd, clsBound).DirtyStatus, AddressOf oBnd_DirtyStatus
```

While this does fix the error it does not get called when the DirtyStatus event is raised.

oBnd is defined as 
`Private WithEvents oBnd As Object`
It is global to the form

oBnd gets set as

```
        oBnd = New clsBound(mvarBUDConnection)
        AddHandler oBnd.DirtyStatus, AddressOf oBnd_DirtyStatus

        oBnd.Load(CInt(txtTrans.Text))
        BuildPage(oBnd)
```

Or

```
        oBnd = New clsClaim(mvarBUDConnection)
        AddHandler oBnd.DirtyStatus, AddressOf oBnd_DirtyStatus

        oBnd.Load(CInt(txtTrans.Text))
        BuildPage(oBnd)
```

The oBnd_DirtyStatus sub, that I am trying to attach to, looks like this

```
Private Sub oBnd_DirtyStatus(IsDirty As Boolean) ' Handles oBnd.DirtyStatus
    Me.Text = "QFix"
    If IsDirty Then
        Me.Text = "QFix - Pending Save"
        btnSave.Enabled = True
    Else
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I attach a handle to this event?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to implement your own INotifyPropertyChanged. If the 2 classes are so similar, it seems a common base class which has the event declared would simplify/clean things up.  Or, a custom `IDataChanged` interface might work.  It should also avoid having to use Reflection to access properties.

Comment: The classes are not really that similar; the public methods are similar but the data being carried is very different.
The classes basically represent database tables.

Comment: Then, an interface might be the way to simplify things,  either INotifyPropertyChanged or your own IDataChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can both get Events working and get away from using Reflection to access properties.  Even given `the public methods are similar but the data being carried is very different` it should still possible to use OOP/Inheritance.

```
Public Enum ClaimBoundType
    None            ' error!!!!
    Claim
    Bound
End Enum

Public MustInherit Class ClaimBase
    ' type tracker usually rather handy
    Public Property ItemType As ClaimBoundType

    Public Sub New(t As ClaimBoundType)
        ItemType = t
    End Sub

    ' low rent INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event DataChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' "universal" prop: works the same for all derived types
    Private _name As String = ""
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If value <> _name Then
                _name = value
                BaseDataChanged(Me)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    ' props which must be implemented; 1 or 100 doesnt matter
    MustOverride Property CurrentValue As Integer

    ' methods which must be implemented
    MustOverride Function DoSomething() As Integer

    ' raise the changed event for base or derived classes
    Protected Friend Sub BaseDataChanged(sender As Object)
        RaiseEvent DataChanged(sender, New EventArgs())
    End Sub
End Class
```

You'd have to do some basic data analysis to figure out which Properties and Methods can be implemented in the base class (as with `Name` above) and which in the inherited classes.  There are usually at least some which can be done in the base class.

Your derived classes can implement the methods in *totally* different ways and load data from where ever:

```
Public Class Claim
    Inherits ClaimBase   ' the IDE will add all the MustInherits when
                         ' you press enter
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(ClaimBoundType.Claim)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function DoSomething() As Integer
        ' what happens here can be completely different 
        ' class to class 
    End Function

    Private _CurValue As Integer = 0
    Public Overrides Property CurrentValue As Integer
        Get
            Return _CurValue
        End Get
        Set(Value As Integer)
            If _CurValue <> Value Then
                _CurValue = Value
                OnDataChanged("CurrentValue")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    ' name of prop that changed not actually used here, but
    ' is usually good to know (use custom args or INotifyPropertyChanged)
    Public Sub OnDataChanged(pname As String)
        ' fire shared datachanged event
        MyBase.BaseDataChanged(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

#### How to Use Them

Now you can implement them without resorting to `Object`, subscribe to the event and not have to use Reflection to get/set properties:

```
 ' 'generic' object variable: DONT/CANT USE [New] w/ClaimBase
 Private myCB As ClaimBase
 ...
' set it as a Claim instance... 
'   This is perfectly legal because Claim is also a ClaimBase Type:
 myCB = New Claim

 ' hook up the event handler
 AddHandler myCB.DataChanged, AddressOf cb_DataChanged
```

You can *declare* your object variables as `ClaimBase`, but you cannot create an *instance* of `ClaimBase` since it is `abstract`/`MustInherit`.  Since the event is part of the base class, there is no problem with syntax. The form level handler:

```
' Use standard (sender, e) signature
' (CA will object to other signatures:)
Private Sub cb_DataChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' do change stuff here
    ...
End Sub
```

Best of all, you can reference properties directly:

```
cbObj.Name = "Ziggy"         ' will fire the event from the base class
cbObj.CurrentValue = 42      ' fires event from the Claim class
```

I added the `ItemType` property so you can tell them apart at run time (ie when you hold the mouse over a `ClaimBase` object variable).  If/when there are Type specific properties/methods to access, cast it (from what you said, there cant be any of these now):

```
If cbObj.ItemType = ClaimBoundType.Claim Then
    CType(cbObj, Claim).ClaimSomething = 5
End If
```

Also use `ClaimBase` as the declaration Type for `Lists` and method signatures also to allow either type to be passed rather than boxing them (converting to `Object`):

```
Private cbList As New List(Of ClaimBase)
   ...
' just an example of the declaration
Private Sub AddThingToList(cb As ClaimBase)
    cbList.Add(cb)
End Sub
```

---

I did not go into `INotifyProperty` in order to focus on Inheritance, though the basics of it are in that base class.  It is a more systemic way to implement the DataChanged/DirtyStatus event and detection.